# Java reading properties file from web directory

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I'm trying to read a `config.properties` file from my JARs local directory where it's run from a website. I have tried a bunch of different code from Streaming it to getting the class path, etc. Finally the one I'm trying now is the following code:

```
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("./config.properties");
        if(f != null) {
            prop.load(f);
            db = prop.getProperty("database");
            dbuser = prop.getProperty("dbuser");
            dbpass = prop.getProperty("dbpass");
            host = prop.getProperty("host");
            iloc = prop.getProperty("iloc");
        }
```

This evaluates perfectly while testing and running from inside Netbeans, but the second I place it on the web and run it, it no longer finds the config file even though it's the same file in the same directory. I've tried with the `./` and without, still same result.

Comment: This tries to read a file from the current directory. The current directory being the directory from which the `java` command, used to start the web server, is executed. Why don't you use an absolute file name?

Comment: Because it needs to be run on a shared server environment no matter where it's placed it needs to be able to read it's config file. :(

Comment: Then embed the config file in the webapp itself, and use Class.getResourceAsStream() (if it's in WEB-INF/classes or in one of the jars in WEB-INF/lib), or ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() if it's in the webapp's root folder or in a subdirectory.

Comment: I was going to, but it needs to be a plain text file editable from the outside at any time from FTP, hence the flat file.

Comment: haha should have said applet from the start

Comment: (added applet to tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to have some absolutes or some run time params. What we do is have an app home as a system property. thus when starting java on windows its /app1 but on a server its /etc/app1

Using the -D when launching java or javaw

```
java -Dapp.home=/etc/app1 -Dapp.other=somevalue my.package.AppMain
```

Then in our app we have a FileUtils class that reads this in static init and has a static getter for it.

Sample

```
public class FileUtils{
    private static File appHome = null;
    static{
        String home = System.getProperty("app.home");//-D that you specify or some standard that java has see javadoc
        if(home == null){
            //logger as needed
            home = "/app1";

        }
        appHome = new File(home);
    }


    public static File getAppHome(){
        return appHome;
        }


    ...
```

a website - running java as the web server/ app server has a file system too. if you do not have access to it then you cant edit the config also right? if you know the path to the config but cannot change the java command you could do something like this:

**Suggestion 1**
on your dev system make an arbitary file like /dev/randome4343433Name.txt if this file exists you know yur in dev and use that path else go for the path in the server.

**Suggestion 2**
Or use the path on the server.
Even if the server is linux and dev is windows you can do this just use this slash / and make the same file system in the dev drive but do not mention the drive letter in code. so if on server its at /etc/app1/config.txt then on local in drive you start make a etc\app1 folder and put config there and uin code use "/etc/app1/config.txt"

Comment: As I said above, it's run on a website through an HTML page not from CLI. Sorry.

Comment: you mean its an applet? or you do not have access to the java command?

Comment: if its an applet then you need to use a URL connection as the applet is running on the client browser and not on the server. see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

For java.applet.Applet or JApplet use Gets the URL of the document in which this applet is embedded. then make a new URL adding the path to config.txt, open the input stream on URL and you can read the file on the client.

remember everything you do is on client, so you cannot write back unless you have a jsp page on server and connect to that using some security (password) from the applet

Answer (score 0):

In commons-configurations jar  there is this class:

PropertiesConfiguration cfg = new PropertiesConfiguration("filePath");

Just check it